# Confusing modulo in c

Tags: c, floating-point, modulo

I'm a bit confused with modulo in c. Trying the following examples:

```
double d = 4912;
int a;
a = (int) d%100;
printf ("%d \n", a);
```

Answer is 12. Fine, that's what I'm expecting. Now I try this:

```
double d = 49.12;
d = d*100;
int a;
a = (int) d%100;
printf ("%d \n", a);
```

Answer: 12. Again what I'm expecting. But now:

```
double d = 49.12;
int a;
a = (int)(d*100)%100;
printf ("%d \n", a);
```

Answer: 11! That's definitly not what I expected. But I have no idea why. oO

Comment: Rounding errors probably. Is d*100 4912.00000000000001 or 4911.999999999999999?. It's not the modulo either, it's the (int)

Comment: Try `printf("%.20g\n", 49.12);`.  What is your result?  IS it "49.119999999999997442"?

Comment: Tried, that's 49.119999999999997

Comment: Isn't it answering your question?

Comment: I think so, but I don't understand, why I see this rounding error in only one case. :/

Comment: @XSized For `double` of the form `xx.yy`, about half of them will encode a `double` a bit above the mathematical `xx.yy` and about half below.  The `(int)` in `(int)(d*100)%100` call will split those groups to `yy` and `yy-1`  camps.

Comment: Is there a reason not to close this as a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)?

Comment: @XSized: The C standard allows a C implementation to use extended precision in intermediate calculations. So `(int) d*100` may apply `int` to a value that is very very near, but less than, 4912. When a value is assigned to an object, the rules require it be converted to the target precision. So `d = d * 100;` would round that value to the nearest `double`, which is apparently 4912.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes. The answers in that question explain little and do not well address specific issues that people ask about. Promiscuously closing questions as duplicates of that one deters people from learning about floating point and precludes building up a repository of matched floating-point questions and answers. It is like answering every C question where somebody is tripped up by sequence points, integer promotion, *etc.* as a duplicate of “Is C broken?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` as a 64-bit floating point number cannot represent every number coded as text. In can encode exactly about 2<sup>64</sup> different numbers. `49.12` is not one of them.

Given the *binary* nature of most `double`, the closest `double d` value is about `49.119999999999997`.

The result of `(int)(d*100)%100` is then simply 11.

---

On another platform,the result may have been 12.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, now I understand the problem!

Comment: There is more going in here. This answer only gives a possible reason `(int) (d*100) % 100` evaluates to 11. It does not explain why, after `d = d*100;`, `(int) d % 100` evaluates to 12. OP may be using an implementation that uses extended precision in intermediate calculations.

Comment: @XSized Note that your `printf("%.20g\n", 49.12);` reported 49.119999999999997 and mine reported 49.119999999999997442.  That is certainly due to the quality of the `printf()` function and not due to a difference of the `double` value code is using.  Some `printf()` better handle the lower digits better than others.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, certainly far more going on.  Your suggestion about intermediate results may occur at higher precision is good - as usual.  Still focusing on OP's likely initial understanding needs before rambling about in the details about precision `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and the rest.